# How to drop fields from avro data in kafka streams

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have an avro data with fields `userid, email, orderid, totalcost, address .....`
I want drop some fields from the data in kafka streams

I have tried this to drop both the email and orderid field

```java
avrodata.peek((key, value) -> System.out.println("incoming " + value))
        .filterNot((key, value) -> value == value.get("email"))
        .filterNot((key, value) -> value == value.get("orderid"))
        .peek((key, value) -> System.out.println("processed " + value));
```

and also this using the getter from the Avro Maven plugin generated class

```java
avrodata.peek((key, value) -> System.out.println("incoming " + value))
        .filterNot((key, value) -> value == value.getEmail())
        .filterNot((key, value) -> value == value.getOrderid())
        .peek((key, value) -> System.out.println("processed " + value));
```

but the second peek shows that no filtering is happening. also i am not sure if filterNot is the correct solution

i also try using `mapValues` but cant figure out how to map multiple fields

thanks.

Comment: `value == value.get("email")` or `value == value.getEmail()` doesn't seem right in any case. Not even `equals()` would make sense here this seems to be a "value container" that has sub-elements and a container never is the same as the element it contains. Maybe try `value.get("email") == null` or something similar (I don't know the format here) to basically find out whether `value` represents an email address.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I already tried that also, still no field is been dropped. I think the answer might lie with "mapValues"  but I still don't get how to map multiple fields

Answer (score 0):

You don't "drop fields" with `filter`, you drop *records*.

I order to drop fields, you need to use `mapValues` and **return a new object without those fields**.

e.g.

```
stream.mapValues((value) -> {
  return FooBuilder
      .withEmail(value.get("email"))
      .withOrderId(value.get("orderId"))
      .build();
});
```

Avro shouldn't matter, other than you'll need a new schema for the "reduced object" or make the not-set fields as nullable.